# how to compare two dates columns with common category in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a data set of of the same category. I want to compare the two date columns of the same category

I want to see if DATE1 less than in values in DATE2 of the same CATEGORY and find the earliest DATE it is greater than

I'm trying this but i'm not getting the results that I am looking for

```
df['test'] = np.where(m['DATE1'] < df['DATE2'], Y, N)

CATEGORY    DATE1           DATE2           GREATERTHAN      GREATERDATE
0   23          2015-01-18      2015-01-15      Y                2015-01-10
1   11          2015-02-18      2015-02-19      N                0
2   23          2015-03-18      2015-01-10      Y                2015-01-10
3   11          2015-04-18      2015-08-18      Y                2015-02-19
4   23          2015-05-18      2015-02-21      Y                2015-01-10
5   11          2015-06-18      2015-08-18      Y                2015-02-19
6   15          2015-07-18      2015-02-18      0                0
```

Comment: Are your `DATE1` and `DATE2` columns stored as pandas `DateTime` objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
df['DATE1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE1'])
df['DATE2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE2'])

df['GREATERTHAN'] = np.where(df['DATE1'] > df['DATE2'], 'Y', 'N')

## Getting the earliest date for which data is available, per category
earliest_dates = df.groupby(['CATEGORY']).apply(lambda x: x['DATE1'].append(x['DATE2']).min()).to_frame()

## Merging to get the earliest date column per category
df.merge(earliest_dates, left_on = 'CATEGORY', right_on = earliest_dates.index, how = 'left')
```

Comment: follow up question - what if i wanted to compare the days +5 days as  like,      df['GREATERTHAN'] = np.where(df['DATE1'] > (df['DATE2'])+5 , 'Y', 'N')  -- how can i achieve that

Comment: you need to change the days you want to add as a time (not as a int) by defining a variable as 5 days by using --- pd.Timedelta(5, unit='D')